# Swap content from old freighter to new freighter?

Tags: no-mans-sky

How can I swap all the content of my old freighter to a new one?

I think about all my storage containers, hydroponic trays, fleet command rooms (all the things which I can not teleport on the GUI).

What about all my frigates?

Answer (score 7):

First findings after buying my 2nd freighter:

- You have to swap every item in the inventory from the left (old) to the right (new) freighter manually - the same as you do for swapping a starship
- All your storage containers are gone. BUT: If you build them new on the new freighter, the content of the same container number will reappear automagically (content of old #1 is reaccessible in new container #1)
- All your command rooms are gone. BUT: If you build them new, the former mission will reappear including all the current participating ships
- All your portable base building products are gone
- All frigates return back to the new freighter after their mission is completed

Comment: As @PeterCo said. You basically lose everything built on the old freighter. If you are freighter hunting in order to replace your current freighter, it is best to delete everything you have built on the current freighter, so as to at least reclaim building materials so you can build them again on the new freighter.

Answer (score 6):

Many years later the manual procedure is no longer needed. provided that you update to the last game version.

**Starting on the 3.5 Prisms update, freighter bases are now automatically transferred when you change your owned freighter**. Notice that this does NOT include the freighter inventory content / upgrade modules.

[image: Official Moveable Freighter Bases feature description from the official Prisms update page]

Full info on the Prisms update available [here](https://www.nomanssky.com/prisms-update/).

Comment: One gotcha: inputs and outputs of refiners will not be preserved.

Comment: @sj26 because a free bug should be always included.

Answer (score 4):

For future people that hit this thread...

When you find a new freighter you want, don't buy it immediately.  Go back to your star ship, launch into space, and summon your existing freighter to the vicinity.  Then you can land on your existing freighter and strip it down, drop stuff in storage containers and/or your ship inventory to have enough room.  Delete the storage containers last to make sure you can offload to them.  Control rooms **CAN** be deleted and rebuilt without losing current missions.

Once your original freighter has been stripped down, then you can go over and buy the new one, transfer inventory, and rebuild all of your rooms.

I have done this twice so far, where the only built out areas left on the freighter I was giving up were the straight line path from the hanger bay to the bridge, I even zapped out the original passages.